# Тревога на пользователях

Tags: поддержка, тревоги, профиль-участника

Можно ли поставить тревогу на пользователя? Например, пользователь может в раздел "О себе" добавить: спам ссылки, угрозы, призывы к террористическим действиям или, как в [данном случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/274033/masalta), оскорбления в сторону участников ruSO. Регулируется ли как-то этот вопрос?

**UPD:** К сожалению ссылка уже не актуальна, поскольку пользователь изменил информацию в разделе "О себе".

Comment: а что там было, в двух словах?

Comment: @Grundy участники, которые флагнули [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744408/qiwi-api-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript) были названы нехорошими людьми.

Comment: и это было добавлено в раздел "О себе"? забавно :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Непосредственно на участника поставить "флаг" нельзя. Нет такого функционала. Можно отметить тревогой любое из сообщений автора с выбором варианта "требуется вмешательство модератора", где расписать сложившуюся ситуацию.

Если же участник не имеет ни одного сообщения, можно написать в [чат сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462), там регулярно появляются модераторы, которые смогут среагировать на проблему. Например, [недавно было обнаружено много спамерских аккаунтов без единого сообщения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/339911).

Comment: Нет, не надо в чат. Только тревога на сообщении.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вам не кажется, что подобные правки некорректно делать без соответствующего обоснования?

Comment: В этой ситуации я подумал, что будет корректно, но я могу ошибаться. Если хотите — я дам свой ответ и откачу обратно ваш.

Comment: @NickVolynkin откатить любой может, а вот обосновать правку — только Вы сами.

Comment: Аргументы: 1) уведомления в чате плохо отслеживаются. Может никто не отреагировать, могут несколько модераторов. Мы уже просили не использовать чат  для тревог. 2) это привлекает лишнее внимание к человеку. Будет плохо, если к конфликту присоединятся ещё люди из чата.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если модератор в чате, это будет куда быстрее флагов (я знаю, как долго они обрабатываются порой). То что другие участники чата увидят что-то уже публичное проблемой не является, имхо. Сидящие в чате и так обычно знают чуть больше о сообществе, чем не заходящие в чат. Ну и может быть ещё крайняя ситуация - у участника нет сообщений.

Comment: Если модераторы слишком долго обрабатывают обычные тревоги — это отдельная проблема. Мы выборы провели, чтобы её решить. За последний месяц среднее время обработки тревоги — 0 дней, 4 часов, 24 минуты, а за всё время — 1 дней, 9 часов, 8 минут.

Comment: А если пользователь не оставил нигде следов, кроме как в [профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276024/does-progressive-offer-non-own)? Является ли данная информация в разделе "О себе" допустимой?

Comment: [+1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276111/jubilee-car-insurance-mauritiu)

Comment: @Kazantsev пишите в чат, как я предложил в первой версии ответа

Comment: @Kazantsev спамеров уже во всю [обсуждают на мете мет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/339911).

Comment: еще [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276039/typical-car-insurance-rates-fl). нет +10 http://prntscr.com/hhkb0n

Comment: а все аккаунты появились 3 дня назад