# Проверка тревог на сообщениях

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Почему-то по некоторым вопросам очень долго проверяются мои тревоги. Я бы даже сказал, что эти вопросы просто «теряются» и никто их не просматривает. Вот некоторые из вопросов:

1. [Склонение слова во множественное число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746277/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)
2. [Поиск подматрицы в матрице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748891/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5)
3. [Open Data хакатон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747928/open-data-%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD)

**P.S.** А кто проверяет тревоги и через какой раздел сайта?

Comment: большинство тревог проверяются модераторами

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от типа тревоги:

- Тревоги на комментариях обрабатываются только модераторами.
- "Требуется вмешательство модератора" - модераторами.
- "Спам / Оскорбление" - модераторами + движок сам минусует в момент постановки тревоги + автоматически удаляет такие сообщения после 6 тревог.
- "Не являются ответом" / "Низкое качество" - забрасывает пост в очередь проверки низкокачественных сообщений. Там сообщение обрабатывается обычными участниками. Через час, если сообщение еще не удалили, тревога доходит до модераторов.
- "Должен быть закрыт" - считается тревогой только при постановке участником с репутацией меньше 3000. Забрасывает сообщение в очередь на закрытие. Обрабатывается обычными участниками с репутацией больше 3000.

В модераторской очереди тревог сейчас пару сообщений. В очереди на закрытие - 350+ :(

Comment: У модератора есть суточные лимиты на очереди?

Comment: @alexolut не уверен.  Когда-то проверял, но не помню результат.

Comment: @alexolut пока я был единственным активным ромбоносцем, копал очереди безлимитно.

Comment: @Nofate отдать все ромбы Нофейту! Тогда заживём!

Comment: Кстати, получается, что если до 3к репутации не набрал на прокурора 500 полезных тревог -- то его уже и не получить?

Comment: @AK вполне получить. только тревоги закрытия перестают быть тревогами и превращаются в голоса. все остальные - все еще считаются тревогами.

Answer (score 3):

Тревоги обрабатываются участниками с ромбами в именах, по-простому, [модераторами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) (есть еще и другие люди, не представленные в этом списке). Иногда они филонят, но как [показывает статистика](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6384/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85/6385#comment25018_6385) (приходится верить на слово, так как эта информация недоступна простым смертным), время реакции на тревогу уменьшилось с увеличением количества ромбоносов на две боевые единицы.

Некоторые тревоги модератор не готов принять или отклонить по тем или иным причинам, поэтому они просто висят, пока не истечет срок их действия.

О статусе ваших тревог можно узнать, если кликнуть на списке «полезных тревог» [в профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) (блок «влияние»).