# Блокировка профилей

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, блокировка

Мне вот интересно: что делают с профилями людей, которые настоятельно не хотят задавать вопрос вежливо и ещё ругаются?

Если блокируют учётную запись, то на какое время?

К примеру, вот кто-то задает вопросы и там использует грубые слова. Он не ругается матом, но всё равно, на мой взгляд, здесь нельзя так.

Это не сайт *18+*, где такое можно.

Я правлю вопрос, но автор не мирится с этим и опять [возвращает  его](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/777884/revisions) в начальное состояние.

Если я что-то не знаю про сообщество - то скажите мне.

Если здесь так принято, то получается я зря ставлю тревоги на такие вопросы и на людей, которые всё равно не хотят принимать мои поправки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Этот вопрос я напрасно задал? Вы давно здесь чем я и знакомы с сайтом хорошо.

Comment: Вопросы вообще редко бывают напрасны) Этот - не исключение. Но будет лучше, если вопрос будет максимально обезличен, дабы мы обсуждали здесь допустимые нормы лексики в вопросах, а не личности отдельных участников. Т.е. ссылки на профили явно излишни, если случай не чрезвычайный. А в данном случае я лично вижу лишь некоторое несовпадение мнений.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да я изменю вопрос. Но вообще то можете мне сказать конкретно я прав или нет? Вы ведь модератор. И если я что то не знаю про сайт то просветите мне.

Comment: @Arhad Спасибо вы дали ответ который мне нужен был.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, тогда выношу свои комментарии в ответ.

Comment: Лично я не вижу ничего криминального в его варианте вопроса. В [словаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/хрень) не говорится, что это плохое слово, более того, говорится, что оно просторечное и [эвфемизм](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/эвфемизм) - _нейтральное по смыслу и стилю слово_. Так что в данном случае всё было вполне приемлемо.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, на профиль действительно не надо, а вот на вопрос с примером - всё-таки надо, а то уж слишком оторвано от жизни смотрится...

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я про вопрос ничего и не говорил)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если автор исходного сообщения затевает войну правок, как было в вашем случае, можете обратиться к [кому-нибудь из ромбовых модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) через [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Обратиться — значит упомянуть где-нибудь в своём сообщение ник через собачку. Пример:

> @Qwertiy, тут участник откатил мою правку со смягчением сквернословия. Прошу принять меры.

И следом второе сообщение, с URL вопроса или ответа (движок чата автоматически преобразует его в плашку с заголовком вопроса и началом его тела).

А дальше модератор [либо сразу его заблокирует (если всё совсем плохо), либо проведёт воспитательную беседу (если ещё есть шанс)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6703/208074).

Comment: Чат актуально использовать, если нет места, где поставить тревогу. Если же такое место есть, то лучше ставить именно тревогу. Связанная тема: [Тревога на пользователях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6384/176217).

Answer (score 4):

Как всегда всё зависит от конкретного случая.

Бывают ситуации, когда участник находится в смятённых чувствах и начинает ругаться матом и оскорблять всех подряд. В таком случае мы, конечно, баним. Срок бана настраиваемый, но он возрастает после каждого следующего бана. Был случай бана на год, например.

Обычно же конфликт вполне угасает сам собой, как только будут потёрты вызывающие конфликт сообщения.

Бан — неприятная, а потому — крайняя мера. Использовать мы её не любим. А любим гасить конфликты без применения карающего молота. Гораздо лучше решать проблемы в рамках конструктивной дисскуссии, даже если это и сложно порою. Если сложно — обычно можно просто пойти поспать — а утром конфликт уже не будет казаться таким важным.

Comment: Да я все это понимаю, и мне вообще не нужен конфликт. Просто мне приятно когда здесь все вежливо. И без каких либо выражений.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, прекрасно вас понимаю) Вежливость - НЯшна)