# Клоны пользователей

Tags: обсуждение, марионетки

Что делать, если пользователь создал несколько аккаунтов?

Например:

- [первый аккаунт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303641/adil-kabdygazinov)
- [второй аккаунт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321889/adil-azrael)

Убедиться можно по вопросам:

- [Вопрос от первого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923201/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82)
- [Вопрос от второго](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926390/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Comment: @VladSpirin То, что многие так делают, не значит, что так делать надо. Модераторы не обязаны сидеть в чате, равно как и обычные участники чата не обязаны выслушивать информацию о чьих-то марионетках. Штатный механизм для жалоб на марионетки - тревоги и форма обратной связи.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я не то имел ввиду, что они обязаны там сидеть, конечно же тревога, это первое что нужно нажать и описать ситуацию. Но вот если реакции нет, то в чат самое оно, ведь там модераторы каждый день бывают, хотя. Нет. Твое описание более верное. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае нарушения участником правил сайта следует ставить тревогу на наиболее подходящем элементе: сообщении или комментарии. Если подходящих элементов нет, то можно обратиться к смежному вопросу: [Тревога на пользователях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6384/176217)

Но стоит иметь в виду, что создание клонов не всегда является нарушением правил. Если один аккаунт не делает ничего такого, что не может сделать другой, то нарушения, как такового, нет. Например, не голосует за сообщения клона, не использует клона для обхода блокировок и т.п. Однако, стоит иметь в виду, что некоторые рьяные участники имеют странное хобби по поиску возможных клонов и уведомляют об этом администрацию в чате. Таким образом, даже безобидные клоны, не нарушающие правила, могут быть неожиданно объединены в один аккаунт. Если такого хочется избежать, следуют явно указать в профиле о наличии клона, не нарушающего правил, и жить спокойно.