# Каковы критерии "безобидности" аккаунтов-клонов, и следует ли сразу отмечать клона тревогой?

Tags: обсуждение, марионетки

Ранее задавался [очень похожий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8459/288409), в ответе на который сказано:

> ...стоит иметь в виду, что создание клонов не всегда является нарушением правил. Если один аккаунт не делает ничего такого, что не может сделать другой, то нарушения, как такового, нет. Например, не голосует за сообщения клона, не использует клона для обхода блокировок и т.п. Однако, стоит иметь в виду, что некоторые рьяные участники имеют странное хобби по поиску возможных клонов и уведомляют об этом администрацию в чате. Таким образом, даже безобидные клоны, не нарушающие правила, могут быть неожиданно объединены в один аккаунт.

Но остается неясным один момент: при том что обычный участник обнаруживший мультиакк не имеет технической возможности точно определить причину создания клона (для обхода блокировки, или "прост захотелось") - стоит ставить тревогу для проверки, или оповещать модераторов следует только в случае очевидных нарушений со стороны клона?

Поясню суть дилеммы:
С одной стороны - когда клоновод только создает дубли своих вопросов (что не является нарушением, если я верно понял процитированный ответ), он этим особо не мешает, т.к. с дубликатами вопросов можно успешно бороться голосованием за закрытие, а у модераторов и так хватает забот.
Но с другой стороны - рядовому участнику неизвестно обо всех действиях клоновода (о том что тот успел натворить до того, как обнаружил себя дублем вопроса), и с этой точки зрения, проверка "странных" участников воспринимается логичной.

В идеале, хотелось бы увидеть в ответе список критериев, по которым рядовой участник может отличить "безобидного" клона от "опасного". А если такие критерии выделить невозможно - то хотя бы общую логику, которой следует руководствоваться в таких ситуациях... потому что они повторяются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Критерий, как мне кажется, довольно простой и может быть следующим. Если есть хоть малейшее подозрение на накрутку голосов/просмотров/знаков..., или попытка обойти наложенное на оригинальную учётную запись ограничение, например, на публикацию вопросов/ответов, то стоит ставить тревогу для модератора (в случае дубликатов вопросов также предлагать закрыть с соответствующей резолюцией, чтобы посты объединить/слинковать). Модератор имеет чуть больше инструментов для проверки добропорядочности действий участника, чем у любого другого рядового пользователя.

При этом для самостоятельной проверки подозрений стоит посмотреть описании профилей потенциальных клонов, может быть там уже указано, что один из них является "вспомогательным" аккаунтом, не нарушающим правила пользования сайта. Так же стоит поискать упоминание имени (и id) подозрительных учётных записей на Мете. Может быть уже был какой-то разбор ситуации с данным участником.

Иногда недобропорядочный участник может сам спалиться, например, забыв "переключить" аккаунт и ответив/прокомментировав от имени клона.

Comment: То есть, получается что опасными действиями клонов по сути являются только накрутки чего-либо, а все остальное (включая появление новых клонов того же участника) не является основанием для тревоги - правильно понимаю? _//Уточняю потому что логика такой оценки опасности не совсем ясна (почему базе знаний "количество фантиков" у отдельных участников вредит больше, чем засорение мультиучетками и дублями некачественных вопросов)._

Comment: @yar85 если кто-то завёл клона, потому что ему заблокировали возможность постить вопросы/ответы, и делает это с новой учётки, то надо тоже ставить тревогу - дописал об этом тоже.

Comment: Этот ответ содержит достаточно подробностей чтобы вывести общий порядок действий: первым делом убедиться что клоны не для накруток (явное нарушение, на которое сразу тревога) ► проверить наличие пояснений в профилях клонов, и на Мете ► попытаться самостоятельно оценить вероятность наличия блокировки у участника, посмотрев на предыдущие вопросы его клонов (идентичны ли вопросы, имеют ли они отриц. рейтинг) и сверившись с памятью (если помнится что участник многократно удалял вопросы своих клонов) ► отметить тревогой только если такая вероятность (наличия блокировки и ее обхода) оценена высокой.

Answer (score 0):

Модераторов стоит уведомлять, если участник нарушает правила. Не нарушает - очевидно, нет и повода для обращения.

Ergo:

> Каковы критерии “безобидности” аккаунтов-клонов, и следует ли сразу отмечать клона тревогой?

1. Не нарушает = безобидный.
2. Нет нарушений - не стоит и флагать.

---

Нарушения в подавляющем большинстве случаев сводятся либо к обходу question ban, либо к взаимным накруткам.

Бывает также, что участник создал вопрос как незарегистрированный, а позже зарегистрировался под другой учёткой (в т.ч. с другого устройства), но по задаваемым вопросам и/или используемуму никнейму/аватарке видно, что один и тот же. В этих случаях раньше связывались с участником, объединяли через КМа.

Comment: Взаимная накрутка - это всё же не клонами делается.

Comment: Да, очевидно, что нарушения надо отмечать тревогой, такие случаи не вызывают вопросов. Неясным тут было другое, и вопрос был задан о другом: стоит ли флагать с виду "мирных" клонов без явных нарушений (для того чтобы модератор проверил их на обход блока), ибо рядовой участник **не может** определить что клон создан для обхода блокировки. Цитата [из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): _«Блокирование функции отправки вопросов не влияет на другие привилегии пользователя (такие как комментирование или голосование) и никак не отображается для остальных членов сообщества.»_

Comment: @yar85 Нет нарушений (не видите нарушений) - не стоит и флагать.

Comment: _«Нет нарушений (не видите нарушений) - не стоит и флагать»_ - тут у нас ситуация вопроса выбора из двух вариантов, и два ответа с ними же  Вариант  "не флагать без явных нарушений" видится мне столь же верным так же как "флагать если есть подозрения", поэтому вопрос и возник. И учитывая равновесие вариантов в ответах, я просто отметил принятым тот ответ который счел более детализированным, но сам до сих пор в том же сомнении с которым пришел посоветоваться. Надеюсь, сообщество поможет голосами тому ответу, который считает верным.