# Участник задает кучу не соответствующих правилам сайта вопросов и не контролирует себя в комментариях. Как поступить?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, нормы-поведения

Вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11849) участник "задает" куча непонятных вопросов

[image]

После [попытки уточнить у него причину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492156/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%82?noredirect=1#comment2674844_1492156) данных действий, ведет себя неприлично

[image]

несет какой-то бред, а сейчас просто минусует популярные вопросы других участников, в том числе мои:

[image]

---

Предлагаю образумить его.

Comment: Уже заблокировали этого грузчика

Comment: Ну вопросы понятные, но, к сожалению, оффтоп.

Comment: Эм, а за что eccs0103 тоже в бане?)

Comment: @andreymal судя по кусочному скриншоту - назвал грузчика обезьяной :D

Comment: @yolosora [ситуация, описанная в литературе](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhnA8.jpg) :)

Comment: @andreymal Я так понял, все или многие той дискуссии банан схватили.

Comment: Большинство вопросов, похоже, возникли в ходе собеседований при устройстве на работу. Имхо, почти нормальные вопросы, если их перефразировать. И малость не для нашего сайта.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если собеседование, то какая-то мутная фирма: "Какой страны образ качать для рутования телефона Samsung Galaxy A72?". И тут же рядом Gentoo+Debian, встраиваемые ЯП, перегрев ноутбука. Больше похоже на то, что участник перепутал stackoverflow и поисковик.

Comment: Или просто был нетрезв и решил позадавать пачку вопросов наудачу, надеясь получить в итоге больше `+` чем `-`.

Comment: @yolosora прикрепил то что осталось от диалога. Никого я ничем не назвал. Если можно считать хоть что-то неприличной, то это второй комментарий из-за чего думаю и получил бан.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Во всех подобных случаях руководствуйтесь [Нормами поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), принятыми на сайте.

Во избежании эскалации конфликтов, [отмечайте сообщения и комментарии тревогой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6384/176217), модераторы должны их рассмотреть в установленном порядке.

Или можете даже написать обращение в [службу поддержки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: Я и обратился в поддержку - как можете видеть, комментарий отмечен тревогой. Но участник получив куча минусов на вопрос, думал что это мы ставим и начал хаотично минусовать наши вопросы. И если мне удалось остановить это после 6 минусов, другой участник получил их пачками.

Comment: @eccs0103 отметка тревоги - это ещё не поддержка. Тревоги уходят к модераторам (участники с ромбами). А поддержка, насколько я знаю, уходит уже к менеджеру сообщества. Правда, [у нас выделенного нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217), если оно всё ещё в силе, поэтому хз кто получает эти письма.

Answer (score -1):

Предполагаю что его взломали. Слишком странное поведение для такого опытного участника.

Comment: "Участник в течение 9 лет 10 месяцев" конечно впечатляет (Хэшкод возвращается...) Но там вопросов то немного, то есть со времен Хэшкода он активно не участвовал. Вполне возможно, что по настоящему вернулся к старому аккаунту, и не заметил, что сайт "слегка" изменился.

Comment: Конечно все может быть, но не представляю какая цель может быть у такого взлома. Одно дело, если бы взломали для накрутки репутации другого аккаунта, другое дело - задать кучу широких вопросов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну [активность ежегодная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11849/%d0%93%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba?tab=activity&sort=all) была всё же какая-то, сложно было бы не заметить изменений.